# Wrong Order when read date from txt file

Tags: date, excel, vba

I have a text file contain like this:

```
03/02/2013 09:47:29 AM||User Name||Open||Normal||Path
03/02/2013 09:47:45 AM||User Name||Close||Normal||Path
03/02/2013 09:47:52 AM||User Name||Open||Normal||Path
03/02/2013 09:47:58 AM||User Name||Save||Normal||Path
03/02/2013 09:47:59 AM||User Name||Close||Normal||Path
03/02/2013 09:48:05 AM||User Name||Open||Normal||Path
03/02/2013 09:48:06 AM||User Name||Close||Normal||Path
03/02/2013 09:48:12 AM||User Name||Open||Normal||Path
03/02/2013 09:55:33 AM||User Name||Save||Normal||Path
03/02/2013 09:55:34 AM||User Name||Close||Normal||Path
03/02/2013 09:55:40 AM||User Name||Open||Normal||Path
```

When i read this line from VBA in Excel and GetDay of date after split it with delimiter "||"
the day is "2", but 2 is really the month.

How can i get this date where day is 3 and month is 2?

Comment: If you have an existing GetDay function, you should show us the code.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the below example should get you in the right direction.

```
Dim row_string as String    'this is a row of text to be manipulated.

Dim sDay as String, sMonth as String, sYear as String
Dim sDateTime as String, sDate as String
Dim rowArr as Variant, elements as Variant, dateElements as Variant

'split the initial row into elements
rowArr = Split(row_string,"||")

'first element is the datetime string
sDateTime = rowArr(0)

'split the datetime string into individual parts
elements = Split(sDateTime," ")

'grab the date element
sDate = elements(0)

'split the date element up into parts
dateElements = Split(sDate,"/")


'Assign date elements to individual variables
sDay = dateElements(0)
sMonth = dateElements(1)
sYear = dateElements(2)


If sDay = "03" And sMonth = "02" Then

'do something here............

End If
```

Or I suppose you could just go for the really simple approach and do..

```
Dim row_string as String

'check the left 5 characters of the entire string
If Left(row_string,5) = "03/02" Then

'do something here...........

End If
```